# Django: registration, login, and logout

Tags: django

New to django, I see quite some tutorials and I'm confused:
is there a built-in something in django that I should use for registration, login and logout? do I need to code my self or is it already available as third party stuff to install? I need guidance on the best practice and fastest, most reliable way.

Comment: [User authentication in Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/)

Comment: Have you tried the [fabulous manual](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/)?

Comment: Thank you, no doubt the documentation is an excellent resource full of wonderful pieces of information that I'm not able to put together because I'm new not only to django but to programming. I have enough Python to proceed with django. It's the full picture I'm after, the one complete walkthrough, step by step, of making the process that will help users to register themselves, log in and log out. It is the end to end process. Of course I wouldn't expect it in an answer but you may have come across a tutorial (that's why they exist) that takes a new beginner by hand through this.

Comment: Or this one :-) https://www.webforefront.com/django/

Answer (score 0):

**Everything** is in the documentation : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/default/#authentication-in-web-requests

Comment: Thank you, no doubt the documentation is an excellent resource full of wonderful pieces of information that I'm not able to put together because I'm new not only to django but to programming. I have enough Python to proceed with django. It's the full picture I'm after, the one complete walkthrough, step by step, of making the process that will help users to register themselves, log in and log out. It is the end to end process. Of course I wouldn't expect it in an answer but you may have come across a tutorial (that's why they exist) that takes a new beginner by hand through this.

Comment: There are a lot of examples on the web. http://www.effectivedjango.com/tutorial/authzn.html is a solution.